# Convert a matrix from mode A to mode B

Tags: r, matrix, logical-operators, r-factor

Very simple question that I want to ask in a general way because it seems to be a recurrent problem, and I would be glad to find a generic way to do it. 
The problem is to convert a matrix of logicals, for instance, into a matrix of factors, for instance, but keeping the matrix structure: number of rows & columns, colnames, rownames. I would like something more straightforward than

```
X2 <- matrix(as.mode(X), ncol=ncol(X)); 
rownames(X2) <- rownames(X) ...
```

I already have figured out this problem for some cases, so I put it here, but some questions remain...

A. into (-->) factors is the one I don't have an easy way to do.

B. 1. logicals --> numeric: uses the '+0' trick

```
BoolMatrix <- matrix(c(TRUE,FALSE),nrow=3,ncol=2)
rownames(BoolMatrix) <- LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(BoolMatrix) <-LETTERS[11:12]
(NumMatrix <- BoolMatrix + 0)
```

B. 2. numeric --> logical: uses directly the condition

```
NumMatrix <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
rownames(NumMatrix) <- LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(NumMatrix) <-LETTERS[11:12]
(BoolMatrix <- NumMatrix == 0)
```

C. numeric <--> character: cannot do better than a 2 liner, directly changing the mode works (and would also work between logicals and numerics, but above solutions are more elegant)

```
CharMatrix <- NumMatrix
mode(CharMatrix) <-"character"
print(CharMatrix)
```

the last solution ("2 liner") works actually for anything that is not related to factors, for which I am having difficulties...

Any idea ? :-)

Comment: I think `BoolMatrix` should be something more like: `BoolMatrix <- matrix(c(TRUE,FALSE),nrow=3,ncol=2)` no?

Comment: there is no `mode` = `factor`

Comment: @mnel - I was about to type the same thing, but then `m` in the answer by @HongOoi returns `TRUE` for both `is.factor` and `is.matrix`.

Comment: @thelatemail -- my comment is true but irrelevant (the mode of a factor is "numeric")

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, I mixed up my examples, but corrected now.

Comment: @ thelatemail @mnel I noticed the exact same thing as you guys soon after posting the question, and I almost edited it. I am glad I didn't! :-)

Comment: I still think it would be better to clarify what you mean by `mode` (compared to the `R` definition of the word

Comment: @mnel I see your point, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `structure`, which attaches a list of attributes to an arbitrary object. For a matrix, the attributes you want are `dim` and, optionally, `dimnames`.

Eg conversion of `X` to a matrix of factors:

```
m <- structure(factor(X), dim=dim(X), dimnames=dimnames(X))
```

Comment: Right on. Just perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Brings me another question: how the hell could someone learn R without SO (and other user-fed internet resources)? There is no path that would have led me to the page 'structure' in the doc...

Comment: Except those are NOT factors. That becomes a character matrix.

Comment: I certainly have. `mf <- structure( matrix( factor(letters[10:1]), 5), dim=c(2,5) ); str(mf)` #chr [1:2, 1:5] "j" "i" "h" "g" "f" "e" "d" "c" "b" "a".  `dput(mf)`
#structure(c("j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"), .Dim = c(2L, 5L))

Comment: `structure(factor(...), dim=...)`, not `structure(matrix(factor(...)), dim=...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @HongOoi's excellent answer, here's a function that will retain all `attributes` of the input matrix (incl. dimensions and dimension names) and change the data to the desired `mode` or to a `numeric` `mode` , `factor` `class`.

```
change.mat <- function(X,ch.fun) {
  do.call(structure,c(list(.Data=do.call(ch.fun,list(X))),attributes(X)))
}
```

Examples:

```
change.mat(NumMatrix,factor)
#  K L
#A 1 4
#B 2 5
#C 3 6
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6

change.mat(NumMatrix,as.character)
#  K   L  
#A "1" "4"
#B "2" "5"
#C "3" "6"

change.mat(BoolMatrix,as.numeric)
#  K L
#A 1 0
#B 0 1
#C 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice addition!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the attributes:

```
NumMatrix <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
rownames(NumMatrix) <- LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(NumMatrix) <-LETTERS[11:12]

FacMatrix <- as.factor(NumMatrix)
attributes(FacMatrix) <- c(attributes(FacMatrix), attributes(NumMatrix))
print(FacMatrix)
#   K L
# A 1 4
# B 2 5
# C 3 6
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: It's pretty much what I wanted to avoid doing, but it's not that long or ugly in this form. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could define matrix methods for `as.*` if you want to save lines of code.